# Assigning Roles to Players Discord Python

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have an issue with assigning roles to discord users in my server with the bot i created.

The code I made is for interacting with FaceIT, which works fine, but I want to be able to assign roles based on how many matches have been played by a user.

With my Code, I know the IDs of the discord user as they are stored in a config file, and the config is loaded into an array called `server_config`

When I run the code, I get this error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Here is a sniplet of my code below

```
@client.command(aliases=["lvl"])
async def assignLvl(ctx):
    global server_config 

    players = server_config[str(ctx.guild.id)]['players']

    # Making sure the server is registered
    check_server(ctx)
    .
    .
    .      this part gets FACEIT data and works
    .
    .
    .
    gzk_srvr = ctx.guild
    for item in hub_data:

        for key in players: 
            if players[key] == item['nickname']:
                if int(item['stats']['Matches']) >= 1 and int(item['stats']['Matches']) < 5:
                    role = get(gzk_srvr.roles, name="First Scrim Attendee")
                    user = gzk_srvr.get_member(int(key))
                    await gzk_srvr.add_roles(players[key], role)

                if int(item['stats']['Matches']) >= 5 and int(item['stats']['Matches']) < 15:
                     role = get(gzk_srvr.roles, name="Lvl 1 Scrimmer")
                     user = gzk_srvr.get_member(int(key))
                     await gzk_srvr.add_roles(players[key], role)

                if int(item['stats']['Matches']) >= 15 and int(item['stats']['Matches']) < 30:
                     role = get(gzk_srvr.roles, name="Lvl 2 Scrimmer")
                     user = gzk_srvr.get_member(int(key))
                     await gzk_srvr.add_roles(players[key], role)

                if int(item['stats']['Matches']) >= 30:
                    role = get(gzk_srvr.roles, name="Lvl 3 Scrimmer")
                    user = gzk_srvr.get_member(int(key))
                    await gzk_srvr.add_roles(players[key], role)
```

I've seen a few questions and answers on this, and tried implementing them, for example where the OP's answer would be to use `await client.add_roles(.....)` but i would also get a similar exception thrown
like `Bot has no attribute add_roles`

I appreciate any help I can get to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the role to the member. To get the Guild's roles, you can use [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get).

```
await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(gzk_srvr.roles, name="Role Name"))
```

Comment: Let me update my Code, I was now able to get the user, check my update in a moment

Comment: Yea, This worked for me, i had to first get the user, which was what i was missing. I already knew the members id, but most of the code don't tell you what method to use to get a member value